# Sum of square roots of binomial coefficients

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, sequences-and-series, binomial-coefficients

**Question:** let 
\begin{equation}
c_n=\sum_{i=0}^n \sqrt{\binom{n}{i}}.
\end{equation}
How does $c_n$ grow with $n$?

My conjecture is that $c_n=\Theta(2^{0.5n}n^{0.25})$.This is because 
\begin{equation}
 0.5^{0.5n} c_n = \sum_{i=0}^n \sqrt{\binom{n}{i}0.5^n}=\sum_{i=0}^n\sqrt{Pr(X=i)},
\end{equation}
for $X\sim Bin(n,0.5)$. The binomial distribution $Bin(n,0.5)$ is approximately the normal distribution $N(0.5n, 0.25n)$. Also, if $Y\sim N(0.5n, 0.25n)$, it is not hard to see that 
\begin{equation}
\int \sqrt{f(y)} dy =\Theta(n^{0.25}). 
\end{equation}
Therefore I believe that it is also true that $0.5^{0.5n} c_n=\Theta(n^{0.25})$. I played with matlab to get some evidence and found that 
\begin{equation}
\frac{0.5^{0.5n} c_n}{n^{0.25}} \approx \frac{\pi}{2},
\end{equation}
for $n=100,1000,10000,100000,1000000$. So the conjecture should be true. So anyone can prove it?

(It turns out that $\frac{0.5^{0.5n} c_n}{n^{0.25}} \approx (2\pi)^{0.25}$ instead of $\frac{\pi}{2}$).

Comment: You should be able to compare the size of the central binomial coefficient with nearby coefficients to see that a small number are close in size to contribute to your sum , and most of the rest do not.  I might expect something like a log n term though. Gerhard "It's Not Quite Hump Day" Paseman, 2017.01.03

Comment: I wouldn't even expect a log term.  The OP's heuristic (comparison with a square root of the matching Gaussian) should be easy to convert to a proof.

Comment: If memory serves, this problem (for any positive exponent) is considered in de Bruijn, *Asymptotic Methods in Analysis*. I don't have access to this book at the moment.

Comment: The last example in <i>Concrete Mathematics</i> is to derive asymtotics for $\binom{n}{k}$ from Stirlings formula and verify $\sum_k \binom{n}{k} = 2^n(1+o(1))$. This somewhat ridiculous finale should be easy to adapt to this problem.

Comment: Note that rather than using Stirling's formula to prove $\sum_k \binom nk=2^n(1+o(1))$, one can instead use $\sum_k \binom nk=2^n$ to prove Stirling's formula.

Comment: @RichardStanley I don't see it in de Bruijn's book, though I could miss it.  There are some similar alternating sums.

Comment: I just looked at de Bruijn: the closest example is $\sum(-1)^{n+k}\sqrt{\binom{2n}k}$, and the proof runs through pp.109-119. It's complicated. Of course, it does consider other real powers of the binomial, not just $\frac12$ (always alternating sums).

Comment: @T.Amdeberhan  dB says that the power is an integer.  I'm not sure the method works for $s=1/2$.

Comment: Please see page 109 and the estimates on page 119. Yes, in the earlier chapters the powers were integers.

Comment: A quick bound from Cauchy-Schwarz is $\sum_{k=0}^n\sqrt{n\choose k}\le \sqrt{n+1}\sqrt{\sum_{i=0}^n {n\choose i}}=\sqrt{n+1} \ 2^{n/2} $. Moreover, since the mass of the binomial distribution is concentrated at the indices $|n/2 - i|\le \sqrt{n}$, the same inequality for $\sum_{|n/2 - i|\le \sqrt{n}}$ would lower the bound to $Cn^{1/4}2^{n/2}$.

Comment: You might find something about asymptotic of this sum also in this math.SE post: [How to evaluate $\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n} \sqrt{\binom{n}{k}} $](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/573537). There is also a generalization: [An asymptotic expression of sum of powers of binomial coefficients.](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/976777). Found [using Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Csum_%7Bi%3D0%7D%5En%20%5Csqrt%7B%5Cbinom%7Bn%7D%7Bi%7D%7D%24&p=1).

Comment: The *alternating* sum $\sum_k (-1)^{n+k} \sqrt{2n \choose k}$ that **T. Amdeberhan** refers to is much subtler to estimate. As it happens this sum (and likewise for other fractional powers) appeared here five years ago: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/85013/alternating-sum-of-square-roots-of-binomial-coefficients

Answer (score 9):

For smallish $k$, we have
$$ \binom{n}{n/2+k} \approx \binom{n}{n/2} \exp(-2k^2/n). $$
So
$$\sum\sqrt{\binom{n}{n/2+k}}
  \approx  \sqrt{\binom{n}{n/2}}  \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-k^2/n}\,dk
  \approx 2^{n/2} (2\pi n)^{1/4}.$$
Of course I did some hand-waving here, but all of this is rigorously justifiable.  Use the Euler-Maclaurin theorm to justify replacing the sum by an integral.

Comment: No need for Euler-MacL.: the integrand increases to and decreases from $k=0$, so the difference between integral and sum is bounded by the central contribution, which is about $n^{-1/2}$ times the integral.  (In fact by Poisson the difference is *much* smaller, but Stirling incurs an approximation error too.)

Answer (score 4):

Define the complex-variable function
$$g(z)=\frac{\sin\pi z}{\pi z}\prod_{k=1}^n\frac1{1-\frac{z}k}.$$
Note $f(k)=\binom{n}k$ for $k\in\mathbb{Z}^{\geq0}$. Moreover, $\sqrt{g(z)}$ is analytic in the region $-1<\Re(z)<n+1$ since $g(z)$ is zero-free there. By the [Residue Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_theorem),
$$\sum_{k=0}^n\sqrt{\binom{n}k}
=\frac1{2\pi i}\int_C\sqrt{g(z)}\,\frac{\pi\cos\pi z}{\sin\pi z}\,dz$$
where $C$ is a closed (positive) contour inside $-1<\Re(z)<n+1$ going around once about each integer $0\leq k\leq n$. Choose $C_R$ as the rectangular along the lines $\Re(z)=-\frac12$, $\Re(z)=n+\frac12$ and $\Im(z)=\pm R$. Thus
$$\int_{C_R}\sqrt{g(z)}\,\frac{\pi\cos\pi z}{\sin\pi z}\,dz
=\int_{C_R}\prod_{k=1}^n\sqrt{\frac1{1-\frac{z}k}}\,\frac{\sqrt{\pi}\cos\pi z}
{\sqrt{z\sin\pi z}}\,dz.$$
So, letting $R\rightarrow\infty$, we arrive at
$$\sum_{k=0}^n\sqrt{\binom{n}k}
=\frac1{2\pi i}\left[\int_{-\frac12+i\infty}^{-\frac12-i\infty}
+\int_{n+\frac12-i\infty}^{n+\frac12+i\infty}
\sqrt{g(z)}\,\frac{\pi\cos\pi z}{\sin\pi z}\,dz\right].$$
The integrand is invariant under $z\rightarrow n-z$, hence it suffices to compute (actually estimate) one of the integrals.

This is where I left off. Perhaps someone can complete the argument.

Comment: I like $\sqrt{g}$, it reminds me the frequency of the pendulum