# The Riemann Zeta Function summing over the Gamma Function

Tags: special-functions, gamma-function, zeta-functions

Has anyone studied a function of the form
$$\eta(s) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\Gamma(n)^{s}} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k!^s}$$
This series is appearing in my research on the volumetric properties of infinite families of polytopes and I am not sure how to evaluate the sum, or if this is a well-known function other than the fact that $\eta(2) = I_{0}(2)$, where $I_{\nu}(x)$ is the modified Bessel function of the first kind as seen [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/419869/sum-of-infinite-series-with-the-gamma-function/419872?noredirect=1#comment897389_419872). I am interested in evaluating this series for any $s \in (1,\infty)$. For integer values of $s$ is it equal to a generalized hypergeometric function?

EDIT: It would be sufficient for my purposes to prove that $\eta(s)$ is finite for any $s \in (0,\infty)$, any ideas?

Comment: You might as well write the sum as $\sum_{k=0}^\infty 1/k!^s$.
I doubt that there's any kind of closed form of this, even
allowing hypergeometric fuctions and the like, for $s \notin {\bf Z}$.
Last year there was some MO discussion of the power series
$\sum_{k=0}^\infty x^k / k!^s$ for $0<s<1$ and real but negative $x$
(it turns out that it's always positive, see the answers at
http://mathoverflow.net/questions/84958  and  
http://mathoverflow.net/questions/85013 ).

Comment: $\eta(s) < \infty$ for $s>0$ is clear by comparison with a geometric series (e.g. show that $k! \geq 2^{k-1}$ for all $k$).

Comment: Thanks! I can't believe I didn't see that, too much geometry dulls the mind I suppose.

Comment: I was always interesting to connect this function with some known say just for $s=1/2$. Its convolution square equals exp, if consider $\sum \frac{x^k}{(\sqrt{k!})}$. May somebody know something nontrivial for this function???