# Integral expressions for Bessel-like power series

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, special-functions, power-series, hypergeometric-functions

I'm interested in power series of form $$f(z)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{z^k}{(k!)^\alpha}.$$ When $\alpha=1$, this becomes $\exp(z)$. For $\alpha=2$ this is a Bessel function and for larger integer $\alpha$ we get a hypergeometric series. These special functions ($\alpha>1$) have integral expressions in form of some integral of an elementary function.

Can anything be said for non-integral values of $\alpha$? If $\alpha>1$ is an arbitrary real number, is there a hope to write an integral expression for the sum? In general, has this form of series been studied anywhere in the literature? Any useful techniques to work with them?

Comment: even something simple as $\sum_{k=0}^\infty 1/\sqrt{k!}$ doesn't seem to be a known special function...

Comment: It may not have a name but I was wondering if it can be written in some form (such as integral expression) to turn the sum into a continuous integral so that one can work with the function in nontrivial ways. It seems like Barnes integrals can be used to produce such expressions, so that may be a potential approach.

Comment: Related: 
https://mathoverflow.net/questions/84958/is-sum-limits-n-0-infty-xn-sqrtn-positive
[for $\alpha = 1/2$, but **fedja**'s accepted answer applies to all
$\alpha \in (0,1)$]; https://mathoverflow.net/questions/85013
[about positivity of  $\sum_{r=0}^n (-1)^r {n \choose r}^{1/2}$, 
again with answers that generalize to 
$\sum_{r=0}^n (-1)^r {n \choose r}^\alpha$ with $\alpha < 1$].

Answer (score 2):

F. Olver, in 'Asymptotics and Special Functions,' chapter 8, has shown that
$$ F_\rho(x):=\sum_{j=0}^\infty \Big( \frac{x^j}{j!} \Big)^\rho \sim
\frac{\exp(\rho \, x)}{\sqrt{\rho}(2\,\pi\,x)^{(\rho-1)/2}} \Big(1+O(1/x)\Big) $$
for $ 0<\rho\le 4$ and $x \to \infty.$  The OP might get some hints from that analysis.

Answer (score 2):

This function is really known and has its name: Le Roy function, cf.
https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/10652469.2018.1472592?journalCode=gitr20

and references therein.